# How to add an icon to the iPhone application with mono touch?

Tags: iphone, ios, icons, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

Could you tell me how to add an icon to the iPhone application with mono touch?

Comment: please describe mono touch...

Answer (score 3):

Inside MonoDevelop

- right click on your project main assembly
- select **Options**
- in the "Project options" dialog select **iPhone Application**

Depending on your version of MonoDevelop (well the iPhone addin) you'll have a different UI. Either a tab named **Icons** are a more visual UI that let you select the different icons to use for your application.

**EDIT**: I could also look like [this](http://ios.xamarin.com/@api/deki/files/29/=dist-app-settings.png) (from http://ios.xamarin.com/Documentation/Building_for_Distribution)